# How to handle Sequelize validation errors with proper way?

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, koa, sequelize-typescript

I'm building simple REST API with Typescript, Koa and Sequelize.

If the client performs an invalid PUT request with empty field "title" or "author" it returns a 500 error. I would rather not report an error like that but like to return a '400 Bad Request' instead.
What is the proper way to do that?

Here is part of the controller:

```js
import {JsonController, Get, Post, Put, Body, Param} from "routing-controllers";
import {Book} from "../models/Book";

@JsonController("/api")
export class BookController {
    @Put("/books/:id")
    async update(@Param("id") id: number, @Body() book: Book) {
        return await Book.update(book, {where: {id: id}});
    }
}
```

And this is the model where I use Sequelize validators as decorators:

```js
import {Table, Column, NotEmpty, Equals, Model, HasMany} from 'sequelize-typescript';

@Table({tableName: 'Books'})
export class Book extends Model<Book> {

    @NotEmpty
    @Column
    title: string;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column
    author: string;
}
```

Error message:

```
"message": "Validation error: Validation notEmpty on title failed,\nValidation error: Validation notEmpty on author failed"
```

Comment: What type is the error? You can write a middleware that catches every exception and transform certain types to a HTTP 400.  I would use a standard format like `application/problem+json` and emit  422 Unprocessable Entity.

Comment: Lucky you, all I get is : `SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Validation error`

Answer (score -1):

try to use ValidationFailed hook

```
import {ValidationFailed} from 'sequelize-typescript'

@ValidationFailed
static afterValidateHook(instance, options, error) {
  throw new ErrorWithStatus(error.message, 400);
}
```

Where ErrorWithStatus is

```
class ErrorWithStatus extends Error {
  status: number;

  constructor(message, status = 400) {
    super(message);
    this.status = status;
}
```

}